# I bear a tail that helps me run

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I bear a tail that helps me run,
>
> I go nowhere when I wear one,
>
> My face can show my many moods,
>
> I hide it if you withhold food,
>
> Pet me right and I’ll repay,
>
> For love and friendship I convey.

**What am I?**

Comment: I suggest you to slightly edit your post to narrow down the number of possible answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit similar, but different and more precise answer

Are you a

> Mobile Phone

I bear a tail that helps me run.

> Wire of charger. Mobile phone will run when it has power.

I go nowhere when I wear one.

> When you are charging your phone, you cannot move it.

My face can show my many moods.

> It's display screen shows different things.

I hide it if you withhold food.

> If you do not give it electricity, it will power down and will see an empty screen.

Pet me right and I’ll repay.

> If you take care of it properly, you can use it for a long time.

For love and friendship I convey.

> Can be a thoughtful gift for your dear one.

Comment: Right answer!!!

Comment: Hmm, I have feeling that 'computer' could be regarded the same as 'mobile phone' here, as they both are correct answers @rsp

Comment: Or, as a matter of fact, any electronic device with some sort of display.

Comment: Which is *exactly* what my answer says

Answer (score 9):

Is it a

> Computer (or any electronic device with a display screen)

I bear a tail that helps me run.

> The lead that supplies the device with electricity so it can run

I go nowhere when I wear one.

> When the device runs it doesn't actually move and it can only move to the lead extension

My face can show my many moods.

> The display screen

I hide it if you withhold food.

> It won't work if you don't give it electricity, just give a blank screen

Pet me right and I’ll repay.

> You have to look after your device. It can break easily.

For love and friendship I convey.

> Who doesn't love a computer?

Comment: good guess, but no.

Comment: Aaaaah thought I had it then! :P

Comment: some parents do not love computers)

Comment: @MolbOrg, true :P